# Were there specific formulaic rules for declaring someone "cherem"?

Tags: cherem

Wikipedia article on [*cherem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herem_%28censure%29) lists the Talmudic rules on what offenses qualified for *niddui*.

However, it doesn't seem to actually list anything specific (aside from monetary issues that caused repeated *niddui*) which would lead to indefinite-period official *cherem* imposed on a person.

Was/is there a codified set of rules of what does and does not rise to the level of *cherem*? (specifically, after 600CE)?

Or was it pretty much up to individual Rabbis based on their personal judgement of what was good for their specific community?

Comment: Yoreh deah 330-something i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for what does rise to the level of *cherem* can be found in Rambam's Mishne Torah ([Talmud Torah 6:14](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910980/jewish/Talmud-Torah-Chapter-Six.htm)) - there are 24 of them, the first five being

> A ban of ostracism is imposed upon a person - either man or woman -
>   for [the following] 24 reasons:
>
> - a) a person who disgraces a sage, even after his passing;
> - b) a person who embarrasses a messenger of a court;
> - c) a person who calls a colleague a slave;
> - d) a person who was ordered [to appear before] a court at a specific time and did not come;
> - e) a person who treats even one point of Rabbinic law with disrespect; needless to say, this applies regarding [matters of] Torah
>     law;
> - [etc](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/910980/jewish/Talmud-Torah-Chapter-Six.htm).

Your question title asks about "the rules for declaring someone cherem" - those can be found in [Talmud Torah 7:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911561/jewish/Talmud-Torah-Chapter-Seven.htm) and following.

If you are asking about the difference between *nidui* and *cherem*, the Rambam explains (in 7:6) that a *nidui* that gets extended twice after 2 periods of 30 days where the person doesn't appear to be released is declared a *cherem*. See also [Moed Katan 16a.](https://www.sefaria.org/Moed_Katan.16a.11?lang=bi)

See also Shulkhan Aruch [YD 334](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.334.1?lang=bi)

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the question. Rambam's list of 24 that you quote is for *niddui* (it's also listed in the Wikipedia article linked in the OP.) The OP seems to be asking for offences that resulted in *cherem* specifically, rather than *niddui*.

Comment: @JoelK but isn't *cherem* a *nidui* that gets extended twice after 2 periods of 30 days where the person doesn't appear to be released of *nidui*? (see 7:6) If that is the question, I will further edit

Comment: You are in all likelihood correct (I have not learned these laws in any depth). It seems to be from reading the question in conjunction with the linked Wiki article that the OP is assuming that there are specific offences that get *cheirem* rather than *niddui*. If the OP’s assumption is incorrect (as you claim) than I would edit the answer to focus on that (assuming you agree with my read of the question).

Comment: @JoelK thanks - I have done so now - that is also my recollection from learning *Moed Katan* but maybe someone will correct me